# Поиск значений на графике

Tags: php, алгоритм, координаты

Задается абсцисса `x` от 0 до 1 и тип кривой (A,B,C,D). Есть постоянный график из 4 кривых (A,B,C,D); нужно найти по графику ординату `y`.
Например, если задано число 0,38 и тип А, то искомым числом у нас будет 2300; если бы тип кривой был B, то искомое значение - 4000.
Для каждой кривой я составил более детальные координаты точек. Не могу придумать алгоритм решения данной задачи, что можете посоветовать господа. Кодить буду на php, построения графика не обязательно в решении, главное найти число.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А кривые берутся из некоей функции? Как описываются кривые, через что?

Comment: Если у вас именно набор точек - воспользуйтесь [интерполяцией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Я не знаю php, так что набросать решение не могу, но, думаю, вы справитесь и сами.

Comment: если графики вычисляемые, то берите исходные формулы и считайте по ним, будет точнее, и, возможно, быстрее. Если эмпирические, то только интерполяция. В любом случае не привязывайтесь к графику, оставьте его как наглядное пособие. Номограммы имеют смысл только для быстрых приближенных вычислений карандашом на бумаге, в машинном варианте их ценность где-то около нуля.

Comment: Кривые набор точек. Они постоянные всегда. Думаю хранить каждую кривую в отдельном массиве. Ни какой функцией они не задаются.

Comment: К примеру кривая А выглядит так: xy (1;200)(0.95;239)(0.9;280)(0.85;335) и тд...

Comment: Harry, подскажите пожалуйста, нужно в сторону Линейная интерполяция направляются ?

Comment: @depredator если точки даны достаточно часто, можно и линейную, хотя для явно выраженных кривых мне кажется лучше сплайновую, второго или третьего порядка

Answer (score 3):

Название вопроса явно некорректно, правильно "**Алгоритм нахождения пересечения двух линейных графиков**"

Буду считать, что кривая у вас задана определенной функцией. Найти пересечение двух графиков очень просто, для начала определите, какими функциями определена у вас кривая на которой необходимо определить точку пересечения по оси y.

Возьмем простую кривую, предположим кривая у нас определенна функцией y = 3x+2.

Теперь, как вы сказали, чтобы найти **второе число от первого** (а правильно точку пересечения по оси y), например от тройки, необходимо добавить к нему новый график x = 3 (вертикальная прямая через x = 3). Получается система уравнений:

```
x = 3;
y = 3x+2
```

Решаем систему уравнений и подставляем x из первого уравнения:

```
y = 3*3+2;
y = 11;
```

**Второе число** равно 11.

Далее, переводите эти вычисления на PHP:

```
$point = 0.38;
$graphFunction = 3*$point+2;
```

Comment: Ну, я бы не сказал, что тут пересечение двух графиков, и тем более линейных...